# Parse complex XML file to get object and its fields

Tags: xml, apache-spark, jaxb, hadoop2, dom4j

Is there a way to parse a complex XML file to get a child element as an object with its fields/members accessible in one read?

I'm working over some code that was passed to me that uses Dom4J and the developer did a read for each node. So for an Object with fields and members, he would read the file four or five times to get each one. To build the object back do you have to make all these calls? It takes 15 secs to run.

Maybe with Dom4J you can get more than one element in one read of the file?

Is JaxB more like that, giving you a reference to the object and its fields in one read?

Is Spark or Hadoop better/faster performance wise?

You see I'm looking to read the XML file and extract an element with child elements, etc to build back the objects in one read.

Let me know what would work best!

Answer (score 0):

Since DOM4J reads the entire file and builds an object graph in memory, there shouldn't be a need to "read" the file more than once.

On the other hand, if you have a schema for the type of document you are processing, JAXB is probably a better alternative.